# Max-flow while restricting flow on subsets of edges to be equal

Tags: linear-programming, max-flow-min-cut, max-flow

Consider a max-flow network $G(V,E,c)$. Consider disjoint subsets of the arcs $R_1,…, R_k$. I want to find the maximum $s-t$ flow such that all the edges in the $R_i$ have equal flow.

Obviously, this is still polynomial time solvable since the constraints are still linear; we can add additional constraints $f_e=f_{e’}$ for a fixed $e\in R_i$ and $e'\in R_i$.

My question is whether there is a *fast* black box reduction to normal max-flow? This would benefit from the near linear time max flow algorithm vs the current matrix-multiplication runtime for LPs.

Comment: Your constraint is very non-local which makes it perhaps less likely that there will be a reduction to standard max-flow. For instance even when capacities are integer valued max-flow with your constraints can be rational.

Comment: OP, maybe edit the question to clarify that you want a *fast* (e.g. nearly linear time) reduction.  E.g. there is a trivial poly-time reduction, and a non-trivial log-space reduction, of your problem to max flow (as max flow is P-complete under log-space reductions).  Conversely, have you looked for a fast reduction from another problem such as 0/1 linear programming *to* your problem?  If there is one that could suggest that what you are looking for is unlikely.

Comment: @NealYoung Are you saying there is a trivial poly-time reduction from my problem to regular max-flow? I don't see it?

Comment: Sure, here's a trivial poly-time reduction: given an instance I of your problem, solve it in poly time using a poly-time LP algorithm, if the answer is yes, output a small feasible instance of the max-flow problem, otherwise output a small infeasible instance of the max-flow problem.